# How to upload Byte array (image) on facebook wall with android application?

Tags: android, facebook, arrays

I am trying to upload one image on facebook wall from drawable folder of my android project. But I am failed ... the message is showing on the wall but image is not on wall .. 
 my sample code is given below ..

```
    Drawable drawable =  ClassName.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        params.putString("message", "Tarun Kumar");
        params.putString("name", "MY Image");
        params.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);
        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());
```

It is showing some error on Log.. like

```
10-03 12:55:55.664: W/Bundle(529): Key message expected byte[] but value was a   java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-03 12:55:55.914: D/dalvikvm(529): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6599 objects / 465168 bytes in   225ms
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at   com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at  com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529): Key format expected byte[] but value was a  java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
10-03 12:55:55.924: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a  java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:  
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
10-03 12:55:55.984: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
10-03 12:55:55.984: D/webviewglue(529): nativeDestroy view: 0x27a548
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529): Key name expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
10-03 12:55:56.014: W/Bundle(529):  at  com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of posting image from app to fb you can't use **me/feed** parameter , you have to use **photos** and request will be

```
mAsyncFbRunner.request("photos", parameters, 
                                    "POST", new WallPostListener());
```